# How can I iteratively add numbered objects to a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a set of "question" objects that I want to put in a list. There are several hundred of these objects, and each is named in a numbered fashion: `question1, question2`, etc.

I can build the list by typing them all in:

```
question_list = [question1, question2, question3, ...
                ... question500]
```

but it seems there must be a simple and easy way to build the list, something like:

```
for i in range(500):
    question_list.append(questioni)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Although ```eval()``` function doesn't  fit best practices you could use it. ```for i in range(500): question_list.append(eval(f"question{i}"))```

Comment: Sounds like the original design should be changed to a list instead of having 500 variables

Comment: Anytime you find yourself with lots of variables with names like `question1`,  `question2`, it's time for a refactor. You will never find a sustainable way forward with that code. It should be `question = []`  and then `question[0]`, `question[1]` Everything will fall into place after that.

Comment: Or a dictionary `{'q1':question1,'q2':question2...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your variables from globals() method.

```
for i in range(500):
   question_list.append(globals()['question{}'.format(i)])
```

Comment: Yes, probably that would be a better solution. globals() returns a dictionary with the current global symbol table, so you can access all the variables form there.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this:

```py
variable1 = "first question"
variable2 = "second question try"

all_values = dir()

output = []
for v in all_values:
  if('variab' in v):
    output.append(eval(v))

print(output)
```

The dir() function shows all string names of the variables, if you only want the output of the variables questionI, you could use the eval() method to get the object inside the questionI (I've supossed that it's a string value). I think that if you change the if statement and use the string 'question' it could work.